# How do i Solve the Radius of the circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Hello I was wondering about this kind of problem I'm having.  Here it is:
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 49
$$

Formula given by our instructor is:  $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.

Comment: What do you want to find? what have you tried?

Comment: you should observe that $49 = 7^2$

Comment: Actually I didn't tried some solutions because I'm confused by the problem WHy?
It's because x^2 + y^2 = 49? isn't that a solution already? not even a math problem i see. Anyhow Please help me. Thank you.

PS: I'm surprised that the radius can be square rooted to 7 our instructor didn't have to do some square rooting options.

Comment: @DanielEstrella0098 The problem is about finding the value of $r$

Comment: @Darksonn Oh i see, Yes i agree to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that $x^2+y^2=49$ and we also know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$

Since we know two things that $x^2+y^2$ is equal to, this means that those things must also be equal.

$$r^2=49$$
If we take the square root
$$r=7$$

Comment: *technically* the radius can be $\pm 7$ (since really the square root is multivalued). However, I'm not sure what a negative radius is of a circle so here's a +1 :P

Answer (score 1):

The reason *why* $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ gives you a circle centered at the origin of radius $r$ is as follows:

Imagine you are given some point $(x, y)$ in the plane.  Now we can draw a right triangle with the hypotenuse being the segment from the origin to $(x, y)$.  If we denote the length of the hypotenuse $c$, then by the Pythagorean theorem, we have $c^2 = x^2 + y^2$.

Now suppose you wanted to describe the set of all points that are distance $c$ from the origin.  Well, they *all* satisfy the same equation: $x^2 + y^2 = c^2$ from the Pythagorean theorem, and that set will trace out a circle of radius $c$.

To conclude, if you are given an equation for the circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, then it's radius is simply $+\sqrt{r^2} = r$.